# SetIcon NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

This is a little Program. The Method should set Icons on buttons to a predefined set of icons. But when I start the Program I get a NullPointerException.

The Method

```
public void SetIcon(boolean isActive) {
    ImageIcon IconBold, IconClipboard, IconKursiv, IconUnderline;
    Ressources Temp;
    if (isActive) {
        Temp = new RessourcesAlternate();
    } else {
        Temp = new RessourcesStandard();
    }
    IconBold = new ImageIcon(Temp.getBold());
    IconClipboard = new ImageIcon(Temp.getClipboard());
    IconKursiv = new ImageIcon(Temp.getKursiv());
    IconUnderline = new ImageIcon(Temp.getUnderline());

    this.btnBold.setText("");
    this.btnBold.setIcon(IconBold);

    this.btnClipboard.setText("");
    this.btnClipboard.setIcon(IconClipboard);

    this.btnKursiv.setText("");
    this.btnKursiv.setIcon(IconKursiv);

    this.btnUnderline.setText("");
    this.btnUnderline.setIcon(IconUnderline);
}
```

The Interface

```
public interface Ressources {
public URL getBold ();;
public URL getClipboard ();
public URL getUnderline ();
public URL getKursiv ();
}
```

Class Standard

```
public final class RessourcesStandard implements Ressources{

final URL CLIPBOARD = Main.class.getResource("Icons/standard/clipboard-icon.png");

final URL BOLD = Main.class.getResource("Icons/standard/bold-icon.png");

final URL UNDERLINE = Main.class.getResource("Icons/standard/underline-icon.png");

final URL KURSIV = Main.class.getResource("Icons/standard/italic-icon.png");

@Override
public URL getBold() {
    return BOLD;
}

@Override
public URL getClipboard() {

    return CLIPBOARD;
}

@Override
public URL getUnderline() {
    return UNDERLINE;
}

@Override
public URL getKursiv() {
    return KURSIV;
}
}
```

Class Alternate

```
public final class RessourcesAlternate implements Ressources{

final URL CLIPBOARD = Main.class.getResource("Icons/alternate/clipboard-icon.png");

final URL BOLD = Main.class.getResource("Icons/alternate/bold-icon.png");

final URL UNDERLINE = Main.class.getResource("Icons/alternate/underline-icon.png");

final URL KURSIV = Main.class.getResource("Icons/alternate/italic-icon.png");

@Override
public URL getBold() {
    return BOLD;
}

@Override
public URL getClipboard() {

    return CLIPBOARD;
}

@Override
public URL getUnderline() {
    return UNDERLINE;
}

@Override
public URL getKursiv() {
    return KURSIV;
}

}
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at de.test.Editor.GUI_Tapped.SetIcon(GUI_Tapped.java:262)
at de.test.Editor.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:79)
at de.test.Editor.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

GUI is my Main Frame
GUI_Tapped is on possible Open Tab

---

Okay,

There was some Problem with the URL Objects. They returned Null.
I edited the whole Thing and uses Strings instead of URLs. Now its working.

Thanks

Comment: And which line in `GUI_Tapped.SetIcon()` is 262?  What are the values on that line?  Do those `get...()` methods on `Temp` actually return valid values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your NullPointerException occurs on the line where you call `setIcon(...)` on your JButtons, then your JButtons are likely null. Check the object whose method is being called on the line throwing the NPE and you'll see.

More importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). You should inspect the line carefully that throws it, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

For example, your stack trace has a key line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at de.test.Editor.GUI_Tapped.SetIcon(GUI_Tapped.java:262) // ***** here *****
   at de.test.Editor.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:79)
   at de.test.Editor.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

This line is the first line of the stacktrace that references one of **your** classes, and so that is the line that is *likely* causing the NPE to be thrown. Please check it carefully, please trace back to where your variables *should* be initialized, and you'll likely solve your problem.